# Getting an invalid syntax error for embed code in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hi i'm trying to create an embed for my custom help command. I thought I did everything right but I receive an invalid syntax error for the first `embed.add_field`. Here is my code for the command:

```
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
 embed=discord.Embed(title="Snoof Bot Commands", description="The guide to all the commands in Snoof Bot", color=0x11add4
 embed.add_field(name="**Admin**", value="yes", inline=True)
 embed.add_field(name="**Music**", value="yes", inline=True)
 embed.add_field(name="", value="", inline=False)
 embed.add_field(name="", value="", inline=False)
 embed.add_field(name="**Other**", value="yes", inline=True)
 embed.add_field(name="**Fun**", value="yes", inline=True)
 await ctx.send(embed=embed))
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Incidentally, you're missing a closing ```)``` on the ```embed=discord...``` line and you have an extra one on the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 syntax problems in your code.

At first, you forget to add `)` to end of the `embed=discord.Embed`.
Then you put an extra `)` in `await ctx.send()`.

So if you add a `)` to `embed=discord.Embed` and delete the `)` in `await ctx.send()`, your problem must be solved.